# Seeking name of a small natural gas generator that will run in all weather

Tags: generator, emergency-preparedness

I want to run a small emergency generator on natural gas (NG).

In the past few years, 3 fuel portable generators have become available.  But the manuals say not to run them in the rain.

"Whole house" NG generators are built to run in all weather.

So, my question is:.  Are there portable NG generators built to run in all weather?  If not, what model whole house generator can I run without hooking it up to my electrical panel and,instead, starting it manually when needed.  (I would run an extension cord to the few appliances I want to power. That is what I do now with a gasoline generator.)

Thanks.

Comment: Build a **very** well ventilated shed (or "doghouse") to keep the rain off. That is effectively what the outer casing on an "all weather" generator is.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Do the walls of the doghouse need to be non-flammable?  How close can the walls be to the generator to minimize risk of fire?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO all of these 'don't run in the rain' rules mean, "don't let it get wet"

So the easy answer is to build a small shed for it, or locate it under sufficient overhang.

I have a gas generator with the same proviso -- don't operate in rain.  I took a barrel, split it in half verticaly, and the generator wears it like a hat.